# To get resolution or max-height of mobile devices even if content size changes on orientation change

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am working with jquery-mobile. I want to show different image sizes based on screen resolution. AS there is no specific way to determine screen resolution, I am making decision on the basis of the screen width.

I also change the size of content, to fit to screen on orientationchange. On orientation change, the screen width also changes. But I want to use the max-width and max-height of device (ie. width & height in landscape mode).

Is there any way to get this screen details?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using CSS Media Queries for example :

```
@media only screen and (min-width:321px) and (max-width:480px) {


}
```

in this css definition you can define text or images for screen who has Min Width:321 and Max Width: 480px.

Hope it's work for you.

Comment: I want to check it using jquery and not css.